# SQUID on Raspberry

Tags: linux, proxy, raspberry-pi, squid

I am trying to implement a proxy server on my Raspberry to log all connections to the internet. Squid (3.4.0) and SARG are installed and running without any problems, but I have still some problems to log internet access with apps via a mobile device i.e YouTube on an Android.

Proxy configuration on devices is done with proxy.pac.

I do not want to cache any pages or file (i.e mp4, etc.). I only want to log the url or files which were downloaded.

In case someone has experience with squid, I am happy to get a hint

My actual squid.conf:

```
 
#  TAG: http_port
http_port 192.168.1.10:3128

#  TAG: icp_port
icp_port 0

#  TAG: no_cache
#We recommend you to use the following two lines.
acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin ?
no_cache deny QUERY

#  TAG: cache_mem
cache_mem 32 MB

#  TAG: cache_dir
# cache_dir ufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache 100 16 256
# cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 100 16 256
cache_dir ufs /mnt/ramdisk 140 16 256

#  TAG: cache_access_log
# cache_access_log /usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log
cache_access_log /var/log/squid3/access.log

#  TAG: cache_log
# cache_log /usr/local/squid/var/logs/cache.log
cache_log /var/log/squid3/cache.log
```

Please keep in mind, I am not an expoert in Linux or Squid. I have used several webpages to install all software tools.

Comment: Those mobile apps are probably developed with security in mind and use HTTPS.

Comment: @DanielB Somehow, it seems to me, `Security` and `Mobile Apps` belong to parallel universes.